# how do you find out which partition maps to which memory device type on embedded linux?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

fdisk command does not provide ample details on this matter. I would like to know which hardware memory device maps to which partition node under /dev/ on embedded linux.

I am running 3.10 embedded linux (yocto project) on i.mx processor 6quad SABRESD for smart devices board.

Comment: Type `mount`.  It should say what each mount point is.  Also `cat /etc/mtab`.

Comment: mount won't show what the device names mean, unless the names themselves are meaningful (which they often somewhat are).  Ultimately you'd need to look at the configuration for MTD or whatever is actually providing them.  This is often compiled into the kernel itself (which should dispense with any doubt about it being on topic here)

Comment: Have you tried `cat /proc/mtd` and `cat /proc/partitions`?

Comment: `cat proc/mtd` happens to give the most meaningful information but it only provides the information regarding 1 device which is an SPI device. Every other command gives meaningful information like file system type, tracks and sectors and block sizes BUT not the device name. This device names appears to be what was assigned in the device tree binder for the hardware. I would like linux to spit that out.

Comment: Linux MTD is major number **90**.  You may use `ls -l /dev/mtd*` or `ls -l /dev/ | grep 90`.  That ties */dev* to the */proc/mtd* if you are using some completely brain dead user space.  MTD is not a device, it is a partition of a device.  Also `cat /proc/cmdline` may have a `root=xxx` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get some information from `udev`, if you're using `udev` in your embedded system (since you're using Yocto, there's a good chance you're using `udev` unless you're really cutting it down to a minimal system).

For example, I'm running Yocto on a BeagleBone Black type system, which has an SD card and an on-board eMMC. The devices show up as `/dev/mmcblk0` and `/dev/mmcblk1`, and which way around it is depends on which memory it booted from (boot device is always `/dev/mmcblk0`).

You can use `udevadm info -a -n <dev-name>` to get information about a device:

```
# udevadm info -a -n /dev/mmcblk0

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/ocp/48060000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:b368/block/mmcblk0':
    KERNEL=="mmcblk0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="1953792"
    ATTR{stat}=="     585      388    38332     3420       78       64     1136     1370        0     2960     4790"
    ATTR{range}=="8"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{force_ro}=="0"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="8"
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{removable}=="0"
    ATTR{capability}=="10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp/48060000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:b368':
    KERNELS=="mmc0:b368"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="mmc"
    DRIVERS=="mmcblk"
    ATTRS{cid}=="1b534d30303030301002b2ffa200b27f"
    ATTRS{csd}=="002f00325b5983b9edb7ff9f16400005"
    ATTRS{scr}=="0225000000000000"
    ATTRS{date}=="02/2011"
    ATTRS{name}=="00000"
    ATTRS{type}=="SD"
    ATTRS{preferred_erase_size}=="4194304"
    ATTRS{fwrev}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{hwrev}=="0x1"
    ATTRS{oemid}=="0x534d"
    ATTRS{manfid}=="0x00001b"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0x02b2ffa2"
    ATTRS{erase_size}=="512"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp/48060000.mmc/mmc_host/mmc0':
    KERNELS=="mmc0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="mmc_host"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp/48060000.mmc':
    KERNELS=="48060000.mmc"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="omap_hsmmc"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp':
    KERNELS=="ocp"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""
```

Then you could make a udev rule to make a symbolic link to the device/partition you're interested in. E.g.:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{type}=="MMC", ATTR{partition}=="2", SYMLINK+="mmcblk-emmc-data"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{type}=="SD", ATTR{partition}=="2", SYMLINK+="mmcblk-sd-data"
```

Which should make a symlink or two:

```
# ls -al /dev/mmcblk-*
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Jul  1 17:34 /dev/mmcblk-emmc-data -> mmcblk1p2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Jul  1 17:34 /dev/mmcblk-sd-data -> mmcblk0p2
```